# Using Visual Studio Debugger with IronPython

Tags: c#, python-3.x, visual-studio, python-2.7, ironpython

I am currently in the dilemma of trying to attach the debugger of Visual studio to a IronPython process.

I have a c# dll that i reference and use in a python scripts, via Ironpython (import clr).

In my c# program i call this python script, again via the IronPython setup.

[C# Code to run Python Scripts and its class method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o50FN.png)

**Steps I have done:**
So far from the research done into this subject I have figured out that you need to add the options dictionary (as seen in the code) and also disable (Just my code) in the debug options. This should allow one to set a breakpoint in the python scripts which visual studio then can hit. Now this does not work for me in both *vs 2019* / *vs 2022*. Only *vs 2017* managed to hit these breakpoints. When I run it with debugger the breakpoints simply say
(The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document)
Again from the research done it looks like the fault is that vs 2019 and 2022 do not support the python version that IronPython uses and as such I am slowly giving up on. The overall goal with my project is simply to try to make the debugger work.

**Question:**
Is there maybe still a way to attach visual studios debugger to a IronPython process and debug the .py file??

PS: I tried both ironPython 2.7 and 3.4.1 alpha

Comment: its confused for me, you want to debug  ironpython.dll?

Comment: Sorry, no I want to debug the python scripts, whilst also debugging my c#. So I can step into the python scripts and out again to c#

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following code in your script:

```
import clr
import System
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
```

Then run your host .NET application under Visual Studio debugger, then run the script.
The script execution should stop in Visual Studio debugger, where you will be able to step, evaluate, etc.

Also note that IronPython supports standard python tracing mechanism (i.e. `settrace`). With this, you could implement a custom debugger/tracer for your scripts. For example, we made such an IronPython script debugger as a part of our product called AlterNET Studio.